# Conditional Breakpoints on Call Stack

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

Is it possible to specify a breakpoint in Visual Studio 2010 that hits only if the calling methods up the call stack meet some specific condition?  For example, and most likely, method name.

I am ideally looking for a solution in Visual Studio itself such as the conditional breakpoint, but I'll settle for testing method names up the stack in code and having a coded breakpoint.

What I'm trying to achieve is to cut out calls from a specific caller.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right click the breakpoint, choose "Condition" and use something like this:

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString().Contains("YourMethodName")
```

Comment: This will string the entire stack trace, making it quite greedy.  Is it possible to iterate, say, the last 5 callers and test their names whilst still plugging the code into the "Condition..." snippet?

Comment: As the condition must be a one-liner, you could use `GetFrame(index)` joined together with `||`, but it would make it even less effective.

Comment: Also, you can't use lambdas in the condition.

Comment: But, anyway, the main performance problem here is with creating the StackTrace object, not with "string-ing" it. :) It's up to you if it is acceptable. If not, you can always test it in your code and use `Debugger.Break`.

Comment: I never implied there was a performance problem.  I was highlighting the fact that calling `ToString` on it sticks the entire stack frame into one string, so I have no control at that point in stating that I'm only interested in the immediate caller, or the 5th caller.  Hence I said it was greedy, as in, checks the entire stack frame not just the parts I'm interested in.

Comment: I'll mark yours as the answer for the further information about conditional breakpoints, but because I need good control over the state of the stack I will have to implement it physically in the code.  I'm going to play with making a static helper that gives me a one-liner that I can put in a conditional breakpoint :-)

Comment: @Adam BTW, if you are only interested in the immediate caller, replace "new System.Diagnostics.Stack **Trace** ()" with "new System.Diagnostics.Stack **Frame** ()". If you're interested in the 5th caller, replace it with "new System.Diagnostics.Stack **Frame(4)** "

Answer (score 4):

The [StackTrace class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) should give you what you need.

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
```