# Conditional Breakpoints on Call Stack with Netbeans and Java

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, conditional-breakpoint

Just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540431/conditional-breakpoints-on-call-stack), when debugging an application, I want to let the application pause at a breakpoint only when the current call stack has a certain method. However, I'm using Netbeans.

In Java the current call stack could be obtained in several ways, like

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

which returns an array of stack trace elements.

Is it possible to iterate through the array (or converted list), check the method names and return a boolean in just one line?

Or, if I need to write a method which checks the array and returns the boolean based on existence of interested method, where should I put it?

Comment: Add a breakpoint where you want it, right click the break point node (in the gutter of margin) and select "Breakpoint Properties"...Fill out the details...

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's not about where I should put the condition, it's about what I should write in the condition box. It requires an expression which returns a boolean; so I am actually asking, how should I check an array of StackTraceElement for desired item in that condition.

Comment: @coolcfan I add a proof of concept in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a private method testing conditions on the stack and call it from the conditional breakpoint. Here is a proof of concept:

```
public class DebugStack {
    private int x = 0;
    private void m1(){
        x++;
        m2();
    }
    private void m2(){
        x+=3;         
    }
    private boolean insideMethod(String methodName){
        for (StackTraceElement stackTrace : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            if (stackTrace.getMethodName().equals(methodName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DebugStack dbg = new DebugStack();
        dbg.m1();
        dbg.m2();

    }
}
```

If you put a conditional breakpoint inside `m2()` with `this.insideMethod("m1")` as a condition the application will pause at the breakpoint only when `m2()` is called from within `m1()`.

Comment: I decide to accept this answer although I finally went to Eclipse to debug the code since it's in a third-party library. Pasting the method body into Netbeans might also work.

Answer (score 1):

For my specific requirement, using lambda and stream in Java 8:

```
Arrays.asList(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
      .stream()
      .anyMatch(e -> e.getMethodName().contains("fetchByABC"))
```